# Spring data neo4j and mogodb mixed up

Tags: mongodb, mixed, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Spring-data-Neo4J and Spring-data-MongoDb together. Calling the save method on UserRepository generates an error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My domain class

```
@Document
@NodeEntity(partial=true)
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@GraphId Long id; 
@Id
private String userId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@GraphProperty
private String username;
```

Below is error log:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jPersistentEntityImpl cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoPersistentEntity
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:79)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:47)
    org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:263)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:165)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:140)
    org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getPersistentEntity(Neo4jTemplate.java:573)
    org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getMappingPolicy(Neo4jTemplate.java:470)
    org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getMappingPolicy(Neo4jTemplate.java:631)
    org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:295)
    org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.save(AbstractGraphRepository.java:106)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:308)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy82.save(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy84.save(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you've combined @Document which is for Spring Data MongoDB and @NodeEntity which is for Spring Data Neo4j. You can't combined these annotations.

**@Document**

> To take full advantage of the object mapping functionality inside the Spring Data/MongoDB support, you should annotate your mapped objects with the @org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document annotation. Although it is not necessary for the mapping framework to have this annotation (your POJOs will be mapped correctly, even without any annotations), it allows the classpath scanner to find and pre-process your domain objects to extract the necessary metadata. If you don't use this annotation, your application will take a slight performance hit the first time you store a domain object because the mapping framework needs to build up its internal metadata model so it knows about the properties of your domain object and how to persist them. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/

**@NodeEntity**

> The @NodeEntity annotation is used to turn a POJO class into an entity backed by a node in the graph database. Fields on the entity are by default mapped to properties of the node. Fields referencing other node entities (or collections thereof) are linked with relationships. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#d0e1621

Comment: Hi krams, thanks for your quick reply, i've tried to create separate entity classes which have their own annotations for MongoDB and Neo4j, but i still get the same error.I found a discussion from google groups, seems someone has the same issue, but unfortunately i cann't find a answer there. Check the [link](http://groups.google.com/group/neo4j/browse_thread/thread/9513a44199c5981e) here. Is there any way to integrate Spring Data MongoDB and Spring Data Neo4j?

Comment: @krams: you can't just quote things without explanations, you don't explain why they couldn't be combined. Plus you are completely missing the point: he wants to combine both, so of course he knows they are different, just trying to make them work together

Comment: @zizibj: have you found a solution? I wanted to use both too but I've got some queries error now. I want to use only one class for both Neo4j and MongoDB, would be a shame to have to use 2, but if there's no other solution...

Comment: @Guillame, there's no need to explain when the quote says it all. There's no need to repeat. Now, if it's not clear with him still, then  let him follow-up. What's obvious to you may not be obvious to others. NodeEntity is for Neo4j. Document is for MongoDb. If you want to combine them, you'll have to verify that with the Spring docs. As far as I remember, you can only combine JPA and other NoSQL stores. But cross-NoSQL stores isn't possible (yet).